# Want to get text from a DIV but getting "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3.7, Django, and BeautifulSoup 4.  I have the below

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
reg = re.compile(r'u\/\[deleted\]')
main_elt = bs.find("button", {"data-main-id": "vote"})
print(str(main_elt.parent))
vote_div = main_elt.parent.find('div')
print(str(vote_div))
print("vote text:" + vote_div.text())
```

Despite the fact that the

```
print(str(vote_div))
```

prints out

```
<div class="outer2 inner4" style="color:#D7DADC">434</div>
```

The line

```
print("vote text:" + vote_div.text())
```

dies with a

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What's the right way to extract the text from a DIV object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `vote_div.text` is a string and you are trying to call it, which is the main cause of this error.

It should be just `vote_div.text` instead of `vote_div.text()`

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a plain attribute, not a function. Use `vote_div.text`.